# Issue while importing resources

Tags: android, import

When I create a project with a Navigation Drawer Activity the imports below works but not when I create a project with an empty activity. 
I really don't understand, they have the same version of android and java...

```
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at the `build.gradle`(app) file. The wizard populates it for you, if you choose the navigation drawer. If you don't use the project creation wizard, you'll have to add the dependencies yourself.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso- 
    core:3.2.0'
}
```